# Macro for Android that presses two buttons at once

Tags: android, user-interface, macros, samsung-mobile

I am trying to implement an new overlay button that can be used in a game in order to use a well known dash bug which requires two buttons to be pressed almost simultaneously. I am using macrodroid for this but ran into two issues, the first one is that the second button is delayed although the cooldown should be only 10ms and the second is that I am not able to press on the overlay whilst holding my finger on the joystick, this just results into not triggering the button. What I am trying to achieve is the assault shield dash on deadcells mobile.

These are my phone details:
Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra,
Android 13,
One UI 5.1